# Workspace configuration

Tags: buffers, window-splitting

I'm working with Emacs on several different projects with several different languages. I'm seeking for solution that could help manage project as `workspace`.

Meaning

- Understand language in use and load appropriate modes (to reduce startup time, I'm trying not to load all at start)
- Restore last buffers and their ordering (last workspace setup)
- Restore default buffers and their ordering (default workspace setup)
- Restore buffers and their ordering in pre-defined setup (special workspace setup, for debugging, for tracing)

Please suggest solutions or point to a way how can I achieve this

Comment: @Dan tried workspace.el and several custom scripts, but overall looks hackish, I'm looking for modes that are have good support and integration

Answer (score 6):

I use a combination of two different tools for project management:[projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile), for switching between projects, and [perspective](https://github.com/nex3/perspective-el), for managing frames within a given project. (The two also integrate well, allowing switching between project states.)

Note that understanding the language in use, in Emacs, is always a function of the mode(s) Emacs loads for a given file, not for a "project" or "workspace." For instance, one project might contain a README in markdown-mode, and also python source, and also SQL schema files.

What neither of those will give you is any kind of save/restore functionality. For that, I believe you want [to save your session via desktop](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html). This *should* get you a good deal of what you want.

To reduce load time, I highly recommend [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package); to make perspective/project switching more pleasant, I highly recommend [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm).

Comment: there's also [persp-mode](https://github.com/Bad-ptr/persp-mode.el), which is similar to perspective but can also save/load perspectives to file

Comment: I suggest `workgroups2` as little different alternative for `perspective`. And, yes, `projectile` is pretty nice.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using Emacs bookmarks, with [**Bookmark+**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus), including, in particular:

- [**Desktop**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#DesktopBookmarks)  bookmarks.
- [**Bookmark-file**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkFileBookmarks) and [**Bookmark-list**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#StateRestoration) bookmarks.
- **Dired** and **Dired-tree** bookmarks. Search for "dired" in the [Bookmark+ doc](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus). There are 100 hits, as there is great synergy between Dired - in particular [**Dired+**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus), and bookmarking.
- Bookmark [**tags**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkTags). Ad hoc tags let you organize bookmarks, and hence the Emacs objects that they target, into sets, including set hierarchies and other set organizations. Tags are arbitrary strings, or strings with associated Lisp values (any values).
- Composite, or [sequence](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#FunctionSequenceVarlistBookmarks), bookmarks, which combine other bookmarks.

See also [Icicles support for projects](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Support_for_Projects).