# How to assign an Emacs buffer to an EXWM workspace based on a regexp?

Tags: window, exwm

I know how to [assign apps to various EXWM workspaces](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33107/in-exwm-emacs-x-window-manager-how-can-i-assign-apps-to-particular-workspaces/45954#45954) thanks to:

```
exwm-manage-configurations
```

But I don't know whether it is possible to assign Emacs buffers to EXWM workspaces in a similar fashion. All the EXWM variables (e.g. `exwm-class-name`, `exwm-instance-name`) that I know how to use in setting the above use `WM_CLASS` and I don't think that Emacs buffers have one (or do they? and if so, how can I find what it is?)

I also know how to customize where and how buffers are displayed within windows using popwin or `display-buffer-alist`. But I don't know if those can be used to assign buffers to workspaces.

[Full workspace configurations can be saved](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24291/workspace-configuration) thanks, for instance, to Bookmark+. But this is not really applicable to what I am trying to do.

### Goal:

My goal is to have all buffers matching the regexp `^\*help\[R:.*$` (R help files in ESS) automatically assigned to workspace 3.

My elisp skills are still limited to write functions and I would appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you very much.